# JHipster angularjs application - Want to perform the login operation with mobile number instead of username

Tags: angularjs, spring, jhipster, yo

I am new to jhipster, so I just created a jhipster application with angularjs and spring. I want to perform the login operation with mobile number instead of username. I have already created a mobile number field during registering new account but on login screen I am not able to find the query where I can change username with mobilenumber.
Basic monolithic app setup is made with yo jhipster.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the implementation of [UserDetailsService](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/security/DomainUserDetailsService.java) and replace how the user is being loaded. For example, change the below line to load user by mobile number.

```
Optional<User> userFromDatabase = userRepository.findOneWithAuthoritiesByLogin(lowercaseLogin);
```

You could also save the mobile number in existing login field. Then you do not need to change anything.